# html5 media capture sharing? is it possible to display the capture in realtime to another page on the site?

Tags: php, jquery, html, media, video-capture

I have just got introduced to the, `html5 media capture API` and im ready to give it a try. I have seen this capture being displayed on the same page but i have yet to see anybody speak on streaming via the server. so what im asking is there a way to avoid `flash`,`silver light` and capture the camera, mic and display this to another page on the site for my other users to view ? like a live stream for the entire site ?

js

```
function fallback(e) {
  video.src = 'fallbackvideo.webm';
}

function success(stream) {
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
  fallback();
} else {
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, success, fallback);
}
```

html:
staff.php - user page that will capture the stream

```
<body>
 <div id="canvas-capture"></div>
</body>
```

cams.php?modelkey=34223r528edfwd23rfwedcwe - page where i want the stream shared

```
 <body>
     <div id="canvas-capture"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display the captured video elsewhere. The success callback that you pass to`getUserMedia` will be invoked with the media stream object from which you can generate a URI that can be specified as the `src` attribute of a `<video>` tag on your other page.

More information and code snippets can be found on the html5rocks [Getting Started with WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) page.

(P.S. I should note that you use the server to relay communication tokens between browsers, but then the streaming happens directly between browsers and is not done through your server).